error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 42: mapping values are not allowed in this context
I'm trying to customize the cpu utilization of different env's into one helm chart by conditional based.  I have my deployment.yaml and values.yaml files configured like below to do conditional cpu utilization based on env, but deployment is failing with the error. I've tried using yaml lint but unable to figure out how to resolve the issue.
Below is my values.yaml file
 metadata:
      name: api
      namespace: trans
    deployment:
      replicaCount: 3
    image:
      repository: registry.rancher.abc.com/capture_trans/transactionapi
      tag: 0.0.11
      pullPolicy: Always
    service:
      name: transactionapi 
      type: ClusterIP
      externalPort: 4545
      internalPort: 4545
    resources: 
      nonprod:
        limits:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 300Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 400m
          memory: 200Mi
      prod:
        limits:
          cpu: 800m
          memory: 1000Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 800m
          memory: 1000Mi    
    ingress:
      env: dev-rancher
      domain: abc.com
    autoscaling:
      enabled: true
      minReplicas: 3
      maxReplicas: 5
      targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
    

Below is my deployment.yaml file and the error I see in the deployment is templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 42: mapping values are not allowed in this context. Any help on this is really helpful.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.metadata.name }}
  namespace:  {{ .Values.metadata.namespace }}
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.deployment.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.service.name}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.service.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 30
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 30
        resources:
  {{- if .Values.nonprod }}
  limits:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.memory }}
  requests:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.memory }}
  {{else}}    
  limits:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.memory }}
  requests:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.memory }}
  {{- end }}    
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /root/tls.crt
            name: config
            subPath: tls.crt
          - mountPath: /root/tls.key
            name: config
            subPath: tls.key
      volumes:
      - name: config
        secret:
          secretName: config
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: default-image-pull-secret

I've tried https://www.yamllint.com/ to link the file but the issues seem to be still there even after removing some spaces and indentation. I'm new to Kubernetes and devops stuff and kind of stuck.

It's hard to troubleshoot your problem with an incomplete .Values file

Updated the thread with complete values.yaml file

Your indentation (important in YAML) is incorrect:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.metadata.name }}
  namespace:  {{ .Values.metadata.namespace }}
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.deployment.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.service.name}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.service.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 30
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 30
        resources:
  {{- if .Values.nonprod }}
          limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.cpu }}
          memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.memory }}
  {{else}}    
          limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.memory }}
  {{- end }}    
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /root/tls.crt
            name: config
            subPath: tls.crt
          - mountPath: /root/tls.key
            name: config
            subPath: tls.key
      volumes:
      - name: config
        secret:
          secretName: config
      imagePullSecrets:


How to get it corrected? I'm new to Kubernetes and still trying to learn.

I corrected it in my answer.

Here:
        resources:
  {{- if .Values.nonprod }}
  limits:

The limits: must be indented one step more than resources:.  The Helm markup doesn't really matter.  (More exactly, the whitespace before {{- is removed, and after }} without a - there is a newline and indentation one step more than the previous step.)
Just below this, at
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.memory }}
  {{else}}    
  limits:

a - inside the {{- else }} action wouldn't hurt.  In the "true" case this block will end with a newline and some additional whitespace.  There's another newline after the {{- end }} so probably nothing actually bad comes of this.
So for this section, fixing that indentation, I'd get something more like
        resources:
{{- if .Values.nonprod }}
          limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.memory }}
{{- else }}
          limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.memory }}
{{- end }}    


But wait!  Your Helm values here have exactly the structure you're trying to output: the values include limits and requests, and each of these have memory and cpu fields.  You could use the Helm toYaml function to convert the structure to YAML, and then indent it appropriately.  You need to pick one resource structure or the other based on the nonprod top-level setting, but the ternary extension function can do that for you.
Maybe shorter is
        resources:
{{- $r := .Values.resources }}
{{ .Values.nonprod | ternary $r.nonprod $r.prod | toYaml | indent 10 }}

Since we're discussing indentation: resources: is indented 8 spaces, so in the next line I indent 10 to get one more step.  This is applied to the output of toYaml, which otherwise begins at the first column.  This means that the first line of ... | toYaml | indent 10 already begins with 10 spaces, so there are no spaces at the front of the line that outputs that.

Should I replace entire resources if condition with below? Do we need to make any tweaks to use ternary extension? I get <$r.prod>: invalid value; expected bool when using the below snippet as is.
resources:
{{- $r := .Values.resources }}
{{ .Values.nonprod | ternary $r.nonprod $r.prod | toYaml | indent 10 }}

Is .Values.nonprod a Boolean value; either exactly unquoted true or false?  Template statements like if and with have an expanded definition of "false" but ternary might be pickier.

These are my values in values.yaml file. Should I add any condition in deployment.yaml?
nonprod:
limits:
cpu: 500m
memory: 300Mi
requests:
cpu: 400m
memory: 200Mi

In the question, you don't have a top-level nonprod: setting at all; you might need .Values.nonprod | default false | ternary ....  I'd also consider just using a top-level resources setting, and splitting the different-environment setups into separate values files you can inject with helm install -f.

Out of my ignorance, what is top-level setting?

There's nothing above it in the nested-dictionary structure.  metadata: in the values in the question is a top-level setting, name: underneath it is not.

Out of my ignorance, what is top-level setting? Also, when I updated the line to           resources:
{{- $r := .Values.resources }}
{{ .Values.nonprod | default false | ternary $r.nonprod $r.prod | toYaml | indent 10 }}
{{- if .Values.nonprod }}
I'm still getting the error "converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 38: did not find expected key" at this line. So without separate values.yaml files for env, will there be any other better approach.?I'm just trying to keep that option as the last

the metadata: and name: haven't been touched from the past deployments. The only thing added was I've split the single set of resources to nonprod and prod resources. If it need's any shifting around, please let me know. I'm very new to this kubernetes stuff and so any assistance is really helpful

Looking at your follow-up question, it's worth noting that the toYaml form after the horizontal line replaces the written-out limits: and resources: blocks in the original question.
